# How to have Ran(A) in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\begin{document}
$\ker(A)$ works!

$\ran(A)$ does not work.
\end{document}
```

How can you have the Ran(A) in the math mode?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175251/how-to-redefine-a-command-using-declaremathoperator/175272?s=1|1.0641#175272

Answer (score 4):

Package `amsmath` does not define all kind of operators, thus `\ran` needs to be defined:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ker}{Ker}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ran}{Ran}
\begin{document}
$\ker(A)$ works!

$\ran(A)$ works after it is defined.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Also `\ker` can be changed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\let\ker\relax % "undefine \ker"
\DeclareMathOperator{\ker}{Ker}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ran}{Ran}
\begin{document}
$\ker(A)$ redefined!

$\ran(A)$ works after it is defined.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with changed \ker]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! How can you replace $\ker$ representing $Ker$ when you have `\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}`?