# How to define ReDeclareLargeMathOperator

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, math-operators

I want alter an existing math operator by applying a macro to it. In the MWE the `\ReDeclareLargeMathOperator` applies the `\ProcessSymbol` macro which in this example changes the color of the symbol as well make a hyperlink to a Wikipedia page.

However, my attempt to adapt the first reference listed below required a few a hack to get the smallest size to be correct for the `\sum` operator.  But, this macro does work properly for the integral as the style is altered.

So, what is the best way to define `\ReDeclareLargeMathOperator` so that I can tweak the symbol yet have the same spacing as the default?

### Notes:

- The black text below is the default operator and the red text is the one that is the one defined with the `\ReDeclareLargeMathOperator` macro.

---

**Sum:** The horizontal spacing does not align with the default symbol.  Even in inline mode there seems to be some additional horizontal spacing added prior to the symbol.

[image]

---

**Integral:** The spacing of the limits of integration are incorrect and the style of the integral symbol does not match.

[image]

### References:

- [How to create my own math operator with limits?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23432/how-to-create-my-own-math-operator-with-limits)
- [How to redefine a command using \DeclareMathOperator](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175251/how-to-redefine-a-command-using-declaremathoperator)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false, pdfborder={0 0 1}, allbordercolors=magenta]{hyperref}

\newcommand*{\ProcessSymbol}[2]{%
    \color{red}\href{#2}{#1}%
}%


%% Adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23432/how-to-create-my-own-math-operator-with-limits
\newcommand*{\ReDeclareLargeMathOperator}[3]{%
    % #1 = name of operator
    % #2 = symbol 
    % #3 = web link
    % ---------------------
    \renewcommand#1{%
        \vphantom{\OldSum}%
        \mathop{\mathchoice%
            {\vcenter{\hbox{\ProcessSymbol{\huge$#2$}{#3}}}}%
            {\vcenter{\hbox{\ProcessSymbol{\Large$#2$}{#3}}}}%
            {\vcenter{\hbox{\ProcessSymbol{$#2$}{#3}}}}%
            {\vcenter{\hbox{\ProcessSymbol{$\scriptstyle#2$}{#3}}}}%
        }\displaylimits%
    }%
}%

%% So that we can test things and also ensure that limit placement matches
%%  the height of where the original definition of \sum placed things.
\let\OldSum\sum
\let\OldInt\int

\ReDeclareLargeMathOperator{\sum}{\Sigma}{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation}
\ReDeclareLargeMathOperator{\int}{\intop}{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral}

\newcommand{\dx}{\mathrm{d}x}%

\begin{document}  
\section{Sum}
In inline math $\OldSum_{i=0}^n i$, and in display math it is:
\begin{flalign*}
    &\displaystyle\OldSum_{i=0}^n i
    \textstyle\OldSum_{i=0}^n i
    \scriptstyle\OldSum_{i=0}^n i
    \scriptscriptstyle\OldSum_{i=0}^n i
    \quad%% so that we can view vertical spacing.
    \displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^n i
    \textstyle\sum_{i=0}^n i
    \scriptstyle\sum_{i=0}^n i
    \scriptscriptstyle\sum_{i=0}^n i &
\end{flalign*}
\noindent
In inline math $\sum_{i=0}^n i$, and in display math it is:
\begin{flalign*}
    &\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^n i
    \textstyle\sum_{i=0}^n i
    \scriptstyle\sum_{i=0}^n i
    \scriptscriptstyle\sum_{i=0}^n i
    &
\end{flalign*}


% ----------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Integral}
In inline math $\OldInt_a^b y\dx$, and in display math it is:
\begin{flalign*}
    &\displaystyle\OldInt_a^b  y\dx
    \textstyle\OldInt_a^b  y\dx
    \scriptstyle\OldInt_a^b  y\dx
    \scriptscriptstyle\OldInt_a^b  y\dx
    \quad%% so that we can view vertical spacing.
    \displaystyle\int_a^b  y\dx
    \textstyle\int_a^b  y\dx
    \scriptstyle\int_a^b  y\dx
    \scriptscriptstyle\int_a^b  y\dx &
    &
\end{flalign*}
\noindent
In inline math $\int_a^b  y\dx$, and in display math it is:
\begin{flalign*}
    &\displaystyle\int_a^b  y\dx
    \textstyle\int_a^b  y\dx
    \scriptstyle\int_a^b  y\dx
    \scriptscriptstyle\int_a^b  y\dx
    &
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\DeclareMathOperator` has a precise semantic, so the name you're choosing is bad. But it's not the real important thing. You surely *don't* want to apply `\huge` and `Large`.

Comment: With operators such as `\sum` and `\bigcup` there's no problem; there is with `\int`, because you won't get the kerning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why changing the symbol for `\sum` into `\Sigma`? It's surely wrong.

Operators such as `\sum` or `\bigcup` can be dealt with in a simpler way; for the integral some more work is needed, if you want to preserve the kerning. Thus the new `\int` command must absorb the possible `\limits` token and then the (optional) limits. Then a red integral is typeset as part of `\href`, with the limits added in the current color.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false, pdfborder={0 0 1}, allbordercolors=magenta]{hyperref}

%% Adapted from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23432/how-to-create-my-own-math-operator-with-limits
\newcommand*{\ReDeclareLargeMathOperator}[2]{%
  % #1 = name of operator
  % #2 = web link
  % ---------------------
  \cslet{\string#1}#1%
  \renewcommand#1{%
    \mathop{%
      \mathpalette{\ProcessSymbol}{{\csuse{\string#1}}{#2}}%
    }\displaylimits
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\ProcessSymbol}[2]{\doProcessSymbol{#1}#2}
\newcommand*{\doProcessSymbol}[3]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{\color{red}\href{#3}{$#1#2$}}}%
}
%% for integrals the above can't work
\makeatletter
\let\linkedint@int\intop
\DeclareRobustCommand{\linkedint}{%
  \let\linkedint@limits\nolimits % default
  \let\linkedint@lower\@empty
  \let\linkedint@upper\@empty
  \colorlet{linkedint@color}{.}%
  \@ifnextchar\limits{\let\linkedint@limits\limits\linkedint@checksub}{\linkedint@checksub}%
}
\newcommand{\linkedint@checksub}{%
  \@ifnextchar_{\linkedint@sub}{\linkedint@checksup}%
}
\newcommand{\linkedint@checksup}{%
  \@ifnextchar^{\linkedint@sup}{\linkedint@do}%
}
\newcommand\linkedint@sub[2]{%
  \def\linkedint@lower{#2}\linkedint@checksup
}
\newcommand\linkedint@sup[2]{%
  \def\linkedint@upper{#2}\linkedint@do
}
\newcommand{\linkedint@do}{%
  \mathop{\mathpalette\linkedint@final{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral}}%
}
\newcommand\linkedint@final[2]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{\color{red}%
    \href{#2}{$#1%
      \linkedint@int\linkedint@limits
        _{\textcolor{linkedint@color}{\linkedint@lower}}%
        ^{\textcolor{linkedint@color}{\linkedint@upper}}%
    $}%
  }}%
}
\makeatother

%% So that we can test things and also ensure that limit placement matches
%%  the height of where the original definition of \sum placed things.
\let\OldSum\sum
\let\OldIntop\intop
\def\OldInt{\OldIntop\nolimits}

\ReDeclareLargeMathOperator{\sum}{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation}
%\ReDeclareLargeMathOperator{\intop}{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral}
\let\int\linkedint

\newcommand{\dx}{\mathrm{d}x}%

\begin{document}  

\section{Sum}
In inline math $\OldSum_{i=0}^n i$, and in display math it is:
\begin{flalign*}
    &\displaystyle\OldSum_{i=0}^n i
    \textstyle\OldSum_{i=0}^n i
    \scriptstyle\OldSum_{i=0}^n i
    \scriptscriptstyle\OldSum_{i=0}^n i
    \quad%% so that we can view vertical spacing.
    \displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^n i
    \textstyle\sum_{i=0}^n i
    \scriptstyle\sum_{i=0}^n i
    \scriptscriptstyle\sum_{i=0}^n i &
\end{flalign*}
\noindent
In inline math $\sum_{i=0}^n i$, and in display math it is:
\begin{flalign*}
    &\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^n i
    \textstyle\sum_{i=0}^n i
    \scriptstyle\sum_{i=0}^n i
    \scriptscriptstyle\sum_{i=0}^n i
    &
\end{flalign*}


% ----------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Integral}
In inline math $\OldInt_a^b y\dx$, and in display math it is:
\begin{flalign*}
    &\displaystyle\OldInt_a^b  y\dx
    \textstyle\OldInt_a^b  y\dx
    \scriptstyle\OldInt_a^b  y\dx
    \scriptscriptstyle\OldInt_a^b  y\dx
    \quad%% so that we can view vertical spacing.
    \displaystyle\int_a^b  y\dx
    \textstyle\int_a^b  y\dx
    \scriptstyle\int_a^b  y\dx
    \scriptscriptstyle\int_a^b  y\dx &
    &
\end{flalign*}
\noindent
In inline math $\int_a^b  y\dx$, and in display math it is:
\begin{flalign*}
    &\displaystyle\int^b_a  y\dx
    \textstyle\int_a^b  y\dx
    \scriptstyle\int_a^b  y\dx
    \scriptscriptstyle\int_a^b  y\dx
    &
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is a slight problem with using \`int^b_a` (as in the last red display mode integral in the image above). But, not an issue for me as I always use \`int_a^b`,

Comment: So, what would be a better macro name to use here
? I don't know how the large operators are defined. Or was your comment related to the fact that I have changed the number of operators (which I agree is sufficient to warrant a different name).  Also, is `\int` the only large operator that is the exception or are the other obvious ones that will need to be tweaked?

Comment: Does using `\cslet{\string#1}#1` and `{\csuse{\string#1}}` do some _magic_? Seems to me that later could be replaced with just `{#1}`?  Oh, I am guessing it has to do with `\doProcessSymbol[3]` which only provided with what appears to be just 2 parameters at invocation. I have seen this sort of _magic_ before, but do not grok it.

Comment: @PeterGrill They define the macro `\\sum` (the second backslash is part of the name), the same trick as for commands with optional argument.