# Interchange `\colon` and `:`

Tags: math-mode, symbols, typography

I know that there is a typographical difference between using `:` and `\colon` in math mode, because `:` is considered to be a relation. However, I use `\colon` far more often than `:`, so I would like to interchange both. Is that possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\colon` and `:` are defined in `fontmath.ltx` using:

```latex
\DeclareMathSymbol{\colon}{\mathpunct}{operators}{"3A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{:}{\mathrel}{operators}{"3A}
```

which makes `\colon` a punctuation and `:` a relation symbol, as you said yourself.

You can swap the definitions:

```latex
\DeclareMathSymbol{:}{\mathpunct}{operators}{"3A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\colon}{\mathrel}{operators}{"3A}
```

---

As egreg noted, `amsmath` has a different definition of `\colon`, which does not rely on TeX's primitive math spacing. To swap the definitions of `:` and `\colon` with `amsmath` you need to make `:` a math-active character (I did that using egreg's [`\DeclareMathActive`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/299805/134574)) and *un*-define `\colon` prior to using `\DeclareMathSymbol`:

```latex
\usepackage{amsmath}
% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/299805/134574
\newcommand{\DeclareMathActive}[2]{%
  \expandafter\edef\csname keep@#1@code\endcsname{\mathchar\the\mathcode`#1 }
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`#1\relax
  \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{#2}%
  \AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`#1="8000 }}
\newcommand{\std}[1]{\csname keep@#1@code\endcsname}
% amsmath's definition of \colon:
\DeclareMathActive{:}{\nobreak\mskip2mu\mathpunct{}\nonscript
  \mkern-\thinmuskip{\std{:}}\mskip6muplus1mu\relax}
% undefine then redefine \colon:
\let\colon\UndefineD
\DeclareMathSymbol{\colon}{\mathrel}{operators}{"3A}
```

Comment: With that I get: `LaTeX Error: Command \`\colon' already defined.` The command for `:` works though. Is there any way to "remove" commands?

Comment: put `\let\colon\relax` before the definition @red_trumpet

Comment: @red_trumpet `\let\colon\relax` or `\let\colon\undefined`. [Related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175251/how-to-redefine-a-command-using-declaremathoperator)

Comment: Thanks now it works! What's the difference between `relax` and `undefined`?

Comment: @red_trumpet What they said :-) `\relax` is a "do-nothing", so usually if a command is equal to `\relax` it is "free to be redefined". `\undefined` is an undefined command. `\SomethingImPrettySureIsNotDefined` would've worked too. The error only appears if `\colon` is defined to be something else though...

Comment: Okay, so using an `undefined` command results in an error (command not found), and using a `\relax`ed command just does nothing. Thanks!

Comment: I'd like to recall that `\colon` has a different definition in `amsmath`.

Comment: @egreg Nice recalling. That explains the error. Thanks :-)

Comment: @red_trumpet See the edit.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I’m gonna define `\UndefineD` in my preamble and sue you when the code fails. `;-)`