# Is it possible to redefine the limit operator to print Lim, not lim?

Tags: math-operators, capitalization

The default limit operator displays “lim” with a small l. I wish to redefine it to display “Lim” that is, with a capital L like shown below.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which documentclass do you use, which math-packages? Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue!

Comment: `\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\Lim}{Lim}`.  If you prefer to redefine the original, `\let\lim\relax
\DeclareMathOperator*{\lim}{Lim}`

Answer (score 10):

You can add `\ShowCommand\lim` to your preamble to see the definition of `\lim`. It'll show

```
> \lim=robust macro:
->\protect \lim  .

> \lim =\long macro:
->\mathop {\operator@font lim}.
<argument> \lim  
                 
l.3 \ShowCommand\lim
```

You can then define something similar for `\Lim` or redefine `\lim` accordingly:

```
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\Lim}{}{\mathop{\operator@font Lim}}% Similar to \lim
\RenewDocumentCommand{\lim}{}{\mathop{\operator@font Lim}}% Replace \lim (lim -> Lim)
\makeatother
```

Note that this default definition differs from how its defined by other packages. For example, with [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath), the definition is

```
> \lim=\protected macro:
->\qopname \relax m{lim}.
<argument> \lim 
                
l.4 \ShowCommand\lim
```

where `\qopname` takes 3 arguments, the first of which is the operator text. You could

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\Lim}{}{\qopname{\relax}{m}{Lim}}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\lim}{}{\qopname{\relax}{m}{Lim}}
```

Best would be to use other tools (like [`mathtools`](//ctan.org/pkg/mathtools)), which help you define operators in a natural way:

```
\usepackage{mathtools}

\let\lim\relax% Remove existing \lim definition
\DeclareMathOperator*{\lim}{Lim}% (Re)define \lim
\DeclareMathOperator*{\Lim}{Lim}% Define \Lim
```

Here's a complete minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

%\ShowCommand\lim

%\makeatletter
%\NewDocumentCommand{\Lim}{}{\mathop{\operator@font Lim}}
%\RenewDocumentCommand{\lim}{}{\mathop{\operator@font Lim}}
%\makeatother


\usepackage{mathtools}

\let\lim\relax
\DeclareMathOperator*{\lim}{Lim}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\Lim}{Lim}

\begin{document}

\[
  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} S_n
  \qquad
  \Lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} S_n
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can either define a new `\Lim` or redefine the existing `\lim`. Both are shown in this MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\Lim}{Lim}
\let\lim\relax
\DeclareMathOperator*{\lim}{Lim}
\begin{document}
$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} S_n = \Lim_{n\rightarrow 0} Z_n$

\[ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} S_n = \Lim_{n\rightarrow 0} Z_n\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is to use `amsmath` (of course you already have it in a math document) and do

```
\renewcommand{\lim}{\operatorname*{Lim}}
```

This is (slightly) less efficient than doing

```
\let\lim\relax %%% undefine \lim
\DeclareMathOperator*{\lim}{Lim}
```

See also [How to redefine a command using \DeclareMathOperator](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175251/4427)

Another strategy is, of course, to do

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\Lim}{Lim}
```

and to use `\Lim`.